# Is there a way I can check if another person is connected to the same vpn?

Tags: openvpn

I am particularly new to these server-side concepts. So my apologies if it is a dumb question. I have 5 VPN configurations in my workspace that are configured to be only used by one person at a time. We use OpenVPN to connect to the server. So I need to ask each and everyone to check which one of them is connected to which VPN. So my question is this.

Is there any way I can check if another person is connected to the same VPN prior to connecting it? If I connect to the VPN that another person is already connected to - it will close the connection of the other person.

I had searched a bit but couldn't find anything relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not deeply familiar with OpenVPN but the concept is fairly common: you have a limited resource that everyone needs to use.

To answer your specific question, I don't believe there is a good way to do this without setting up a check-in/check-out system.  For example, you could have the password be completely random and you have to "check-in" to a separate system to receive the password.  After the user logs in and does her work, they then "check-out" triggering a password reset.

However, another way to overcome this issue is to have a dedicated system for the VPN connection.  Set up a VM that is always connected to the VPN that users can then log into remotely via SSH/RDP/VNC/etc.  All work concerning the VPN has users log in there.

Comment: why you dont have for eqch user a seperate config/user?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Although I have not got the exact answer I was looking for, I kind of have an idea to try it now. I guess I will have to try it to see if it is working. Once again thank you.